# Azure Cloud Service / IIS 8 does not reach client browser after long process to generate PDF report

Tags: azure, logging, timeout, iis-8, web-applications

I'm running a .net web app on Azure Cloud Service, Cloud Service provides a VM running Windows 2012 R2 OS with IIS 8.

Issue occurs when client browser goes to a page to trigger a PDF report generation. Report generation takes about 5-6 minutes. Once report is generated, it redirects to another page to stream the PDF as content type = application/pdf.

However, after the 5-6 min. wait time, I see the PDF report generated on the server side, but the client browser is still "waiting" for a response.

Looking at the IIS logs, I see sc-win32-status 1236 and sc-win32-status 121 entries for the pages requested.

Based on research, I applied the following IIS ApplicationHost settings with no success.

Thoughts?

[IIS ApplicationHost Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQR0P.png)